# Error getting all calendars: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)" Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, compiler-errors, calendar

I have an app that is supposed to load a list of calendars into a pickerview. It works, but only after the app crashes and is opened again. I am not sure why it will not work on the initial opening of the app.

Calendar Permission Request:

```
func requestCalendarPermissions() {
eventInstance.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: {(accessGranted: Bool, error: Error?) in

    if accessGranted == true {
        print("Access Has Been Granted")
        }
    else {
        print("Change Settings to Allow Access")
    }
    })
}
```

Checking the Permission Status:

```
func checkStatus() {
let currentStatus = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event)

if currentStatus == EKAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined {
    requestCalendarPermissions()
}
else if currentStatus == EKAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
    print("Access Has Been Granted")
}
else if (currentStatus == EKAuthorizationStatus.denied) || (currentStatus == EKAuthorizationStatus.restricted){
    print("Access Has Been Denied")
}
}
```

PickerView Code:

```
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return calendars.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return calendars[row].title
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    CalendarField.text = calendars[row].title
    calID = calendars[row].calendarIdentifier
}
```

This error comes up:

> Error getting all calendars: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)"

The app finally crashes because it tries to fill the pickerView and there is no data to fill with. I do load the calendars.

But, for some reason this doesn't happen after the app crashes and is reopened.

Thanks

[Update]

Console out:

> 2016-11-26 18:04:23.856 PTF[98143:2347570] Error getting all
>   calendars: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)" Calendars
>   Loaded 2016-11-26 18:04:23.869 PTF[98143:2347569] Error getting all
>   calendars: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)" Calendars
>   Loaded
>
> Access Has Been Granted 2016-11-26 18:04:25.954 PTF[98143:2347569]
>   Error getting all calendars: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013
>   "(null)" Calendars Loaded
>
> 2016-11-26 18:04:46.620 PTF[98143:2347522] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[**NSArray0
>   objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bb6634b __exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010b5c721e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010bb7dddd -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:] + 93  3
>
>   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010d95311d
>   _TFVs12_ArrayBuffer19_getElementSlowPathfSiPs9AnyObject_ + 125    4   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010d953003
>   _TFVs12_ArrayBuffer10getElementfTSi20wasNativeTypeCheckedSb_x + 147   5   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010d963b8a
>   _TFSag9subscriptFSix + 138    6   PTF                                 0x000000010af8df12
>   _TFC3PTF19MainScreenTableView10pickerViewfTCSo12UIPickerView12didSelectRowSi11inComponentSi_T_
>   + 226     7   PTF                                 0x000000010af8e10a _TToFC3PTF19MainScreenTableView10pickerViewfTCSo12UIPickerView12didSelectRowSi11inComponentSi_T_
>   + 74  8   UIKit                               0x000000010c0d301d -[UIPickerView _sendSelectionChangedForComponent:notify:] + 104  9   UIKit                               0x000000010c0d326e -[UIPickerView
>   _sendSelectionChangedFromTable:notify:] + 370     10  UIKit                               0x000000010c8a560d -[UIPickerTableView _scrollingFinished] + 187    11 
>   UIKit                               0x000000010c8a57fd
>   -[UIPickerTableView scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:] + 30   12  UIKit                               0x000000010c1df821 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal)
>   _scrollViewDidEndDeceleratingForDelegate] + 91    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c1dc362 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal)
>   _stopScrollDecelerationNotify:] + 316     14  UIKit                               0x000000010c1dc5b9 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal)
>   _stopScrollingNotify:pin:tramplingDragFlags:] + 505   15  UIKit                               0x000000010c1d4503 -[UIScrollView _smoothScrollWithUpdateTime:] + 3304
>     16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113fa3bd5
>   _ZN2CA7Display15DisplayLinkItem8dispatchEy + 57   17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113fa3a95 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy +
>   449   18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010baf8964
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 20    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010baf85f3
>   __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075     20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010baf817a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 250    21  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010baeff01 __CFRunLoopRun + 2065  22  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010baef494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420     23  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000011124aa6f GSEventRunModal + 161  24  UIKit
>   0x000000010c0eff34 UIApplicationMain + 159    25  PTF
>   0x000000010af9f36f main + 111     26  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010f30368d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Which line of code causes the error message? And why would your app crash? If your app is crashing because your app doesn't have access to the calendar then you need to fix your code.

Comment: The app has access to the calendars, but after the access is given it is supposed to allow the user to click the textfield and a pickerview pop up with the list of calendars. However, on the initial install of the app the list comes up empty, then crashes. After said crash the app can be reopened and the pickerview is now populated with the list of calendars.

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions. Which line of code is causing the error you posted? Which line of code causes your crash? What is the error message from the crash? If you don't wish to provide details for people to help you, why bother posting the question?

Comment: I have added the console output, before and after the crash. The error that I posted doesn't explicitly call any line of code that is causing it. The line of code causing the crash, I am assuming, is the pickerview didselectrow, because the list of calendars is empty.

Answer (score 14):

I've just run into this problem. After 'requestAccess' the documentation says to call 'reset' on the eventInstance. However even this did not get things working. However getting a new eventInstance did. I'm using objective c, so I release the EKEventStore object I was using and allocate a new one.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Worked for me as well!

Comment: This also worked for me in Objective-c, while calling `-reset` on my store instance did not solve the issue.