# EventKit error getting meetings iOS 11.2.2 on initial load

Tags: ios, authorization, eventkit, ekevent

EventKit showing error when you fetch data for the first time.

[EventKit] Error getting all calendars: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1019 "(null)"
2018-01-17 19:19:22.190518+0530 StickyNoteApp[426:40382] [EventKit] Error getting default calendar for new events: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1019 "(null)"
2018-01-17 19:19:22.190556+0530 StickyNoteApp[426:40382] [EventKit] No object ID provided.  Will not find out if the object exists.
view will appear

[EventKit] Error (1019) in reply block for CADDatabaseFetchCalendarItemsWithPredicate attempt 1/3
2018-01-17 19:24:54.942170+0530 StickyNoteApp[426:40382] [EventKit] Error (1019) in reply block for CADDatabaseFetchCalendarItemsWithPredicate attempt 2/3
2018-01-17 19:24:54.942572+0530 StickyNoteApp[426:40382] [EventKit] Error (1019) in reply block for CADDatabaseFetchCalendarItemsWithPredicate attempt 3/3
2018-01-17 19:24:54.942588+0530 StickyNoteApp[426:40382] [EventKit] All retries exhausted for CADDatabaseFetchCalendarItemsWithPredicate
2018-01-17 19:19:22.242094+0530

Answer (score 10):

It's bug may be!
Anyways, I've got it solved. **Need to create new instance of `EventStore` after granting access as:**

```
    self.eventStore = EKEventStore()
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
        self.eventStore = EKEventStore()//<---------here's trick
        //do stuff
    }
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44415132/5546312)!

Comment: not work for me even I did reset the new instance of EKEventStore